# How do I configure my DbSet to map to a specific table within a specific SqlServer Schema?

Tags: entity-framework

The database I need to build a DAL for is designed with multiple schema, which is causing me some problems:

So, for example, consider these tables within two separate Schema (Suppliers, Deals)

- Suppliers.Suppliers
- Suppliers.Types
- Deals.Deals
- Deals.Types

I have in C#

```
namespace Data.Entities.Suppliers 
{
    public class Suppliers { /* properties mapped to fields in Sql Server table Suppliers .Suppliers */ }
    public class Types { /* properties mapped to fields in Sql Server table Suppliers .Types */ }
}

namespace Data.Entities.Deals
{
    public class Deals { /* properties mapped to fields in Sql Server table Deals.Deals */ }
    public class Types { /* properties mapped to fields in Sql Server table Deals.Types */ }
}


namespace Data.Repositories 
{
    public class EfDataContext: DbContext 
    {
        public DbSet<Suppliers.Suppliers> Suppliers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Suppliers.Types> SupplierTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Deals.Deals> Deals{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<Deals.Types> DealTypes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

but EF is tripping over there being two things named "Types", how do I disambiguate the two using only DbSet?

NOTES:
I am trying to get away from having a .edmx file.

Comment: For the record: EF core has no trouble with this model, but it uses the default schema for the 4 tables that are named according to the DbSets.

Answer (score 0):

To specify schema you can use [TableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.tableattribute(v=vs.103).aspx) on your class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.tableattribute(v=vs.103).aspx) or configure your model using fluent api with ToTable() method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.tableattribute(v=vs.103).aspx)